Probability that normally distributed variables will have a specific ranking
There are $k$ players playing a game, each gives a performance $X_k \sim N(\mu_k, 1)$ and we observe their ranking from best to worst (a permutation of the player indexes). How to calculate the probability of observing a specific ranking if we know $\mu_k$ for every player?
The $X_k$ are independent.
The goal is to compute a MLE of the $\mu_k$ parameters given a set of observed rankings.

Do you want to do this based on a single set of rankings or based on multiple sets of rankings?

@ThomasLumley The dataset contains several observed rankings.

You ask two very different questions.  Computing the distribution of rankings based on $\mu$ is a generalization of a FAQ; the answer is that for $k\ge 3$ you must use numerical methods of integration.  The MLE question is different.  First, the MLE doesn't exist.  You could, however, estimate the differences $\mu_j-\mu_k.$  But the standard errors would be infinite, because you essentially have observed a single realization of the vector random variable $X.$  Maybe you have observed rankings from repeated instances of the game?

BTW, isn't this really just a clarification your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645448/distribution-that-assigns-a-probability-to-each-possible-ranking-of-a-set-of-pla?

@whuber Yeah, both questions are about the same underlying problem. I actually forgot I previously asked the other question.

@whuber Yes, I have observed multiple rankings. Right now I'm looking into solving this with a tool like Stan and implementing a version of the Thurstonian model (which seems to be what I'm trying to do).

Please add the clarifications in comments as an edit to the post. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overseen and can be deleted

@kjetilbhalvorsen I'm not sure which clarifications are you referring to.
